# adjust custom Navigation bar in xcode 4.6 for ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

All App is working fine for ios 7 except the Navigation bar
is there any way to adjust it for ios 7 in xcode 4.6 
i dont want to build this from xcode 5 because it creates too many other issues
Navigation bar issue is the content start from the y=0 which hides in the navigation bar.originally it should start next from the navigation bar

Comment: In 4.6 you can compile only for iOS6, but in my application for iOS6 the navbar on iOS7 is at the correct point. If you compile your iOS6 application for iOS7 on xcode 5 you are gonna have "navbar" problems, because in ios7 the screen default are is the full screen size.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS7 , frame starts below the status bar , so y=0 means it will be under the status bar.
To counter this, you should put y=20.

Comment: means there is no other dynamic way??means i have to put conditions for this??

Comment: In xcode 5 , there is an option to set delta for ios6 and ios7, but I guess in xcode 4.6 you have to do this programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Show the size inspector" in interface builder (xCode 5 only, but doesn't require code at all). Where you can specify delta for any View that you have, so it will look like you want in both iOS6 and iOS7. Note that xCode builds interface for iOS7 without delta's, it applies delta to iOS6, iOS6 etc.

[image: Size inspector can be found here]